# How to delete multiple substrings by their positions in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string, and I have a list of positions of the substrings that I need to delete:

```
text = 'ab cd ef gh'
positions = [[2, 5], [8, 11]]
```

Every element of the list contains start and end position of substring. End position is exclusive, and start position is inclusive. So the string should be transformed to:

```
text = 'ab ef'
```

Length of the list with positions is unknown, so the soultion can't be just hardcoded.

Is there any effective way to delete multiple substrings by their positions? Positions can't overlap.

Comment: What are these values `[2,5]`?

Comment: @AKS indeces [start, end]. Judging by desired output it's [inclusive, exclusive].

Comment: Is `end` index inclusive or exclusive? You have asked a very unclear question and that too without showing what you have already tried to achieve the expected output.

Comment: You can specify the spacing you need using slicing

Comment: Is it possible for positions to overlap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are **immutable**, so in-place deletion is a no-go. And successive concatenation is suboptimal.

You can convert the string to list so it can be *mutated* and simply wipe off the desired positions by **deleting** each unwanted slice. Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to recreate your string:

```
text = 'ab cd ef gh'

lst = list(text)
for i in positions[::-1]: # iterate from behind so index does not shrink inwards
    del lst[slice(*i)]

text = ''.join(lst)
print(text)
# 'ab ef'
```

Note that conversion to list for the mutation of immutable types is also suggested by the docs as best practice:

> Concatenating immutable sequences always results in a new object. This
>   means that building up a sequence by repeated concatenation will have
>   a **quadratic runtime cost** in the total sequence length. To get a **linear runtime cost**, you must switch to one of the alternatives below:
>
> 1. if concatenating `str` objects, you can build a list and use
>      `str.join()` at the end or else write to an `io.StringIO` instance and
>      retrieve its value when complete

Answer (score 4):

You have to offset for future indexes. So we first get the rest of the string (excluding the two indexes) via `text[:2] + text[5:]` and then we also need to offset it too, because we are removing items from the string.  So, we'll add our offset to each position item.

```
text = 'ab cd ef gh'
positions = [[2,5],[8,11]]
offsetNextIndexes = 0
for position in positions:
    text = text[:position[0] + offsetNextIndexes] + text[position[1] + offsetNextIndexes:]
    offsetNextIndexes += position[0] - position[1]
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work easily.

```
" ".join(text.split()[0::2])
```

The slicing will help here to skip some parts, it works as

```
[start:end:difference]
```